# Array mutated while being enumerated from different threads

Tags: ios, arrays, multithreading

I have a rather puzzling problem related to thread safety on iOs.

In a singleton object I have an array that contains dictionary elements. The dictionary elements contain an object and string relating to the resource that are waiting for (images downloaded from the internet). 
When the resource is available (image finished downloading) I retrieve all the delegates from the array that are waiting for that particular resource.

The problem is that the array (mutable) can be modified very frequently (from different threads) and it happens that it's modified when it's being enumerated.

How should I fix this? Should I create a static dictionary that contains mutable arrays for keys? But still the particular array for a given key could be enumerated while something adds another value to it....

Here is the (very not thread safe) code:

```
        - (void)addDelegate:(id<ImageDelegate>)delegate ForFileId:(NSString *)fileId
{
    if (debug) { NSLog(@"[]adding delegate %@ for fileId: %@",delegate,fileId); }
    NSDictionary *d = @{DELEGATE_KEY: delegate,
                        FILE_ID_KEY : fileId};
    [self.delegatesArray addObject:d];
}

- (void)removeDelegate:(id<ImageDelegate>)delegate forImgUrl:(NSString *)imgUrl
{
    NSString *fileId = [Utils formatLink:imgUrl];

    if (debug) { NSLog(@"[]removing delegate %@ for fileId: %@",delegate,fileId); }

    NSDictionary *toRemove;

    for (NSDictionary *crtD in self.delegatesArray) {
        if ([crtD[FILE_ID_KEY] isEqualToString:fileId] && [crtD[DELEGATE_KEY] isEqual:delegate]) {
            toRemove = crtD;
            break;
        }
    }
    [self.delegatesArray removeObject:toRemove];
    if (debug) { NSLog(@"[]removed delegate %@ for fileId: %@",toRemove,fileId); }

}

- (NSArray *)getAllDelegatesForFileId:(NSString *)fileId
{
    NSMutableArray *requiredDelegates = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (NSDictionary *crtD in self.delegatesArray) {
        if ([crtD[FILE_ID_KEY] isEqualToString:fileId]) {
            [requiredDelegates addObject:crtD];
        }
    }
    NSArray *returnedArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:requiredDelegates];
    if (debug) { NSLog(@"[] found %d delegates for fileId:%@",[returnedArray count],fileId); }
    return returnedArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.

1. Don't use fast enumeration. Use a standard `for` loop to iterate the array.
2. Synchronize access to the array so it can only be used by one thread at a time.

Something like this:

```
@synchronize (self.delegatesArray) {
    // do something with the array
}
```

Use the above around every read/write access of the array

Another (better) way to control access is to use GCD. Make use of `dispatch_sync` and `dispatch_barrier_sync`. Use the latter around write access and the former around read access. This has the benefit of allowing multiple readers but only allows one writer and no reads during a write.

Comment: I was thinking about something like this. (I'll try the gcd option) . Will this have a significant performance effect? (we're talking about at most 30-4 reads and writes a seconds)

Comment: Any form of synchronization will have a performance effect. But not as much as the app crashing. :)  Worry about any real performance issue if you encounter one after you get it working properly.

Comment: There is a problem... this array .. contains as delegates cells (collection view or table view) if fast forward - backward scrolling occurs  then sometimesI see the following : a cell will flicker and show various images until the right one is shown.I believe this is because of the barriers? ? Any suggestion?